# How do I start codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie in codeigniter framework.I am totally confused how can I start with CI?
What would be the folder structure ,I am seeing a folder structure by default, but after searching ,all are concerned about a better folder structure

Also it  would be a themeable one .So I/anyone  can simply theme it,without touching the views ,if once  developed 
Please advice me

Comment: Reading the online manual would be your first best step, instead of looking for shortcuts and untainted opinions

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I create a tutorial [How to start with Codeigniter?](http://webinonetutorials.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-start-with-codeigniter.html) that for the beginner but you already need to know about php well. Good luck!

Comment: Link on your answer has been moved so update your answer or give details about it...

Comment: Link redirects to a blog site with this same question and spam answers.

Answer (score 2):

http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/

The folder structure is something which is more advanced.  Don't worry about it until you have something to put into the folders.

The whole point of views is that you're *supposed* to skin them and ignore the rest of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Start by going through the first few tutorials [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/). Don't worry about the folder structure yet, start by understanding [MVC](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html).

Also, Codeigniter has a really helpful [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide). If you get stuck on your way, look there for help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must understand the concept of MVC (Model, View, Controller) that CodeIgniter uses.
Then...
go to your www folder
and: system/application
you now have:
controllers - where all your code goes
views - the html stuff
models - don't worry with this if your newbie
and others...
you also have a tutorial on themes at the URL cwallenpoole gave you.